# How to use Identity with Entity Framework database first in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When I try to use *Identity* with EF **database first**, I get the following error

> Missing partial modifier on declration of type 'MyProject.Models.UserProfile' another partial declration of this type exist.

Basically I get this error because there is a `partial class` called `UserProfile` that exist in `AccountModel` class and another `class` with the same name that represent the `Table` generated using *Identity*.

So what should I do?

Comment: Those are 2 different classes with the same name, correct? Try to put them in different namespaces...

Comment: @ESG I made both `partial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that both classes defined used "partial" modifier.

Comment: It worked, but I had to remove the `UserId` and `UserName` from Entity Framework class, because they already exist in the `AccountModel class.